# Centralized Error Handling for fetchBaseQuery in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

When using Redux Toolkit's `fetchBaseQuery` for making API requests, it is common to handle errors individually for each request by checking the response status and performing error-specific logic.

The question arises: Is there a way to handle errors in a centralized manner when using `fetchBaseQuery` in Redux Toolkit? In other words, can we implement a solution that allows for global error handling instead of repeating error handling logic for each API request?

By centralizing error handling, we aim to streamline the codebase, improve maintainability, and ensure consistent error handling across different API calls. This approach would involve intercepting the response from `fetchBaseQuery` globally and performing error-specific actions such as displaying error messages, updating error state in the Redux store, or triggering certain error-related behaviors.

```
 I tried something here, but does not yeild the results I was hoping for
```

```js
// Create a custom base query
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: '/api',
  // other options...
});

// Create an error interceptor
const errorInterceptor = (baseQueryApi, response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    // Handle error globally
    // Example: Dispatch an action to update error state in Redux store
    store.dispatch(setError(response.statusText));
  }

  return response;
};

// Create a custom fetchBaseQuery with error handling
const fetchBaseQueryWithErrorHandler = (args) => {
  return baseQuery(args).then((response) => {
    return errorInterceptor(baseQueryApi, response);
  });
};

// Create an API slice
const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQueryWithErrorHandler,
  // other options...
});
```